# Figure legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having problems renaming my figure legend. When I try using scale_color_discrete to do this the legend duplicates on the graph:
[image]

This is the code I've used:

```
    Scoping <- read.csv("Data/scoping.csv")

#Enzyme column must be turned into a factor
Scoping$Enzyme <- as.factor(Scoping$Enzyme)
#Creating scatterplot called scopplt
scopplt <- ggplot(Scoping,aes(x=Time,y=PNP,shape=Enzyme, color=Enzyme))+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,120), breaks = c(0,30,60,90,120), name = "[PNP] µM")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,12), breaks = c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12), name = "Time (min)")+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.6))
  
scopplt
# Adding linear regression
scopplt+geom_smooth(method=lm,se=FALSE,fullrange=TRUE,
                     aes(color=Enzyme)) +
  scale_color_discrete(name= "[Enzyme] µM")
```

Does anyone know why this is happening. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide us some data to work with?

Comment: It's because the two aesthetics have different titles for their scales. Try adding `+ scale_shape_discrete(name = "[Enzyme] µm")`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are calling `scale_color_discrete` because you are trying to rename the legend. If that is indeed what you trying to do with that line, you are taking the wrong approach. The problem is that you are changing both the color and shape of the points by Enzyme, and `scale_color_discrete` only applies to the color. To change the legend title, you can do what teunbrand suggested so that ggplot knows that you want the same title for the color and shape, thereby putting the two legends together. Or you can also replace `scale_color_discrete(name = "[Enzyme] µM")` with `labs(color = "[Enzyme] µM", shape = "[Enzyme] µM")`. My intuition tells me there should be a simpler way of doing this, but I am unable to figure it out at this point in time.